# Will google cloud take money from me in this situation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I registered google cloud account and want to use Text-To-Speech API on my own server with [github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php](http://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php) library.

On API page in block "Pricing" written that using less than 1 millon chracters/month is free. But lower is a note
"Additional charges may also apply from infrastructure you use to call the API"

Question:
This note applies to users google cloud VPS, right? If I will use API how I described (send requests from my own server) first million of characters will be absolutely free? Google wont take a cent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they mean the [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/). So you pay Google only for API, not for server.